# Opening huge mySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigdata

I want to open a Huge SQL file (20 GB) on my system i tried [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) but it seems bigdump dose not support more than 1 GB SQL files is there any script or software that i can use to open,view,search and edit it.

Comment: What is your OS? Are you sure it can handle 20GB file sizes?

Comment: .sql files is just text. you can use any text editor you want on it.... but still, 20gig is a HUGE file to load into ram to fiddle around with.

Comment: i know u can edit it with editors of course not most of them  010 editor can do it but i want to view it ordered as a database not a messy nonsense file

Comment: Just to be clear... you a `.sql` file is not really a database, right?

Comment: um, that should have been "you _know_ a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Workbench should work fine, works well for large DB's, and is very useful...
https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Install, then basically you just create a new connection, and then double click it on the home screen to get access to the DB. Right click on a table and click Select 1000 for quick view of table data.

More info http://mysqlworkbench.org/2009/11/mysql-workbench-5-2-beta-quick-start-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but can you give me a nice tutorial link for that because  i'm not familiar with it thank you

Comment: Sure basically you just create a new connection, and then double click it on the home screen to get access to the DB. Right click on a table and click Select 1000 for quick view of table data. More info http://mysqlworkbench.org/2009/11/mysql-work bench-5-2-beta-quick-start-tutorial/

Comment: thank you very much  i tested it and it worked but i ask you to edit your answer and add tutorial with details for other users with the same problem thank you again

Comment: Yes no problemo. PHP My admin is kind of terrible in comparison, and you're right, large DB's can kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql command line to do basic SELECT queries.

```
$ mysql -u myusername -p
>>> show DATABASES; // shows you a list of databases
>>> use databasename; //selects database to query
>>> show TABLES; // displays tables in database
>>> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = 'somevalue';
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the structure of the database, one way of handling this is by exporting each table in a seperate sql file, as for editing the file, you're limited to opening the raw sql files in notepad or any other text editor. But you probably already knew that.

What are the settings that were used to export the database? People often forget that there's also an option to turn on comments, for big databases it makes sense to turn that off.

To get a more detailed answer have you tried asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/?